# github url style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, github, url-rewriting

I wanted to have users within my website to have their own URL like http://mysite.com/username (similar to GitHub, e.g. my account is http:// github. com/sr3d).  This would help with SEO since every profile is under the same domain, as apposed to the sub-domain approach.

My site is running on Rails and Nginx/Passenger.  Currently I have a solution using a bunch of rewrite in the nginx.conf file, and hard-coded controller names (with namespace support as well).  I can share include the nginx.conf here if you guys want to take a look.

I wanted to know if there's a better way of making the URL pretty like that.

(If you suggest a better place to post this question then please let me know)

Cheers,

Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place this line right at the end of the routes.rb file, ( So that this doesn't interfere with other controller routes )

```
map.connect "/:username", :controller=> "users", :action => "show"
```

in users_controller, use the following line to fetch the user

```
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
```

I don't think this would require any nginx magic or url rewrites.

HTH

Comment: It would involve to blacklist certain usernames to avoid ambiguity with routes defined earlier.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, blacklisting certain usernames would be required.

Comment: There's a good sampling of smart username blacklists here, including Github's in-use blacklist: http://www.quora.com/How-do-sites-prevent-vanity-URLs-from-colliding-with-future-features?__snids__=4909005